# Утечка памяти в программе сортировки на C

Tags: c, сортировка, утечка-памяти

Написал довольной простой код на С, который делает сортировку числам с помощью сдвига .

1. Когда пользуюсь "while((temp < *(arr+j))&& j>=0 )" valgrind  ругается на утечку памяти , но результат сортировки верен (проверено на 50 числах)
2. когда заменяю "int temp2 = *(arr+j); while((temp<temp2)&&j>=0) , сортировка не работает

В чём разница между двумя кодами? В чем проблему с памятью?
Спасибо!

```
*

valgrind -s  --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --error-exitcode=1 ./isort < ../inputs/sort_input.txt > /dev/null
    ==2221== Memcheck, a memory error detector
    ==2221== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
    ==2221== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
    ==2221== Command: ./isort
    ==2221==
    ==2221== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2221==    at 0x10929D: insertion_sort (isort.c:37)
==2221==    by 0x10936D: main (isort.c:56)
==2221==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2221==    at 0x1092DE: main (isort.c:48)
==2221==
==2221==
==2221== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2221==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2221==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 8,192 bytes allocated
==2221==
==2221== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2221==
==2221== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==2221==
==2221== 5 errors in context 1 of 1:
==2221== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2221==    at 0x10929D: insertion_sort (isort.c:37)
==2221==    by 0x10936D: main (isort.c:56)
==2221==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2221==    at 0x1092DE: main (isort.c:48)
==2221==
==2221== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)""
```

- 

Программа :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 50
void shift_element(int*,int);
void shift_element2(int *arr, int i)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        *(arr+1)=*(arr);
        i=0;
    }
    
    
    int prev=*(arr);
    int curr=0;
    if(i>=1)
    {
        while(i>=-1)
        {
            curr=*(arr);
           *(arr)=prev;
             arr++;
             prev=curr;
             i--;
        }
     }
}

void insertion_sort(int *arr,int len)
{
   for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
   {
       int temp= *(arr+i);
       int j= i-1;
      // int temp2 = *(arr+j);

       while((temp < *(arr+j))&& j>=0 )
       {
           *(arr+j+1)= *(arr+j);
           j--;
       }
       *(arr+j+1)=temp;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int arr[N];
     int num=0;
 for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&num);
    *(arr+i)=num;
 }
 insertion_sort(arr,N);
 
 for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
 {
    printf("%d,",*(arr+i));
 }
 
  printf("%d",*(arr+N-1));
 
return 0;
}
```

- 

Comment: Всем спасибо ! Все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

len - 1 (лен минус один) сделай цикл а не от i по len

Answer (score 1):

По утечке памяти - Вам нужно поменять местами условия в цикле `while()`, т.к. при `j == 0` происходит итерация цикла, `j` уменьшается до -1 и на следующей итерации в условии цикла проверяется `temp < *(arr-1)` - а это за пределами массива.

```
while((temp < *(arr+j)) && j>=0 ) // неправильно!!! 
// надо так
while( j>=0 && (temp < *(arr+j)) )
```

В данном случае сначала проверится j>=0 и второе условие проверяться не будет.

А во втором варианте `temp` и `temp2` - фиксированные значения, которые не изменяется в цикле, поэтому сортировка и не работает. И ошибка с памятью никуда не делась!

```
int temp= *(arr+i);   // temp - фиксированное значение, не изменяется в цикле
int temp2 = *(arr+j); // temp2 - фиксированное значение, не изменяется в цикле
while( (temp<temp2) && j>=0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работало с temp2, изменяй его в цикле:

```
while (j >= 0 && (temp < temp2))
{
    *(arr + j + 1) = *(arr + j);
    j--;
    if (j >= 0) // иначе выход за границы массива!
        temp2 = *(arr + j);
}
```

Зачем N - 1? Сделай до N.

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
    printf("%d,",*(arr+i));
 }
// лишняя строка 
printf("%d",*(arr+N-1));
```

Comment: Отлично . Спасибо !